# Calculate month-over-month growth as a percentage in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', dateordered), SUM(orders) - (
SELECT SUM(orders)
FROM c_orders
WHERE orderstatus = 'returned'
)
FROM c_orders
WHERE orderstatus = 'complete'
GROUP BY 1
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
date_trunc  total_orders
2016-08-01 00:00:00 129
2016-09-01 00:00:00 125
2016-10-01 00:00:00 160
2016-11-01 00:00:00 202
2016-12-01 00:00:00 357
```

I want to calculate the month-by-month percent change, starting in August. How could I do that within my SQL query?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using that query?  This is much simpler:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', dateordered) as yyyymm,
       SUM(CASE WHEN orderstatus = 'returned' THEN orders
                WHEN orderstatus = 'complete' THEN - orders
                ELSE 0
            END) as net
FROM c_orders
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Then your question is easily answered using `lag()`:

```
WITH o as (
      SELECT date_trunc('month', dateordered) as yyyymm,
             SUM(CASE WHEN orderstatus = 'returned' THEN orders
                      WHEN orderstatus = 'complete' THEN - orders
                      ELSE 0
                  END) as net
      FROM c_orders o
      GROUP BY yyyymm
     )
SELECT o.*, 
       (net / LAG(net) OVER (ORDER BY yyyymm) - 1) as net_change
FROM o
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

To get the data since 2016-08, you need one more level of subqueries:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM (SELECT o.*, 
             (net / LAG(net) OVER (ORDER BY yyyymm) - 1) as net_change
      FROM o
     ) o
WHERE yyyymm >= '2016-08-01'
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LAG()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) to select `total_orders` from previous row for percentage calculation

```
with total_orders(date_trunc,total_orders) as (
  values
('2016-08-01 00:00:00' ,129)
,('2016-09-01 00:00:00' ,125)
,('2016-10-01 00:00:00' ,160)
,('2016-11-01 00:00:00' ,202)
,('2016-12-01 00:00:00' ,357)    
)
,with_base as (select *,(lag(total_orders,1,0) over (ORDER BY date_trunc))
from total_orders)
select  date_trunc
      , total_orders
      , (case when 0 = lag 
              then 0 
              else total_orders / lag::FLOAT  * 100 end)::INT as percent 
from with_base;
```

Result:

```
date_trunc            total_orders  percent
"2016-08-01 00:00:00",129          ,0
"2016-09-01 00:00:00",125          ,97
"2016-10-01 00:00:00",160          ,128
"2016-11-01 00:00:00",202          ,126
"2016-12-01 00:00:00",357          ,177
```